Problem with new LaTeX marks with \twocolumn
I try to use the new LaTeX marks mechanism with \twocolumn, but I don't get the expected result. I want the first section title and the first subsection title of each page in the header, but it doesn't work if these are in the second column. They do when they appear in the first column. I don't know if that is a misunderstanding on my part or just a bug.
I use \FirstMark{2e-left} and \FirstMark{2e-right-nonempty} as described in The LaTeX Companion, 3rd ed.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=1in, headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% begin header configuration
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Start fancyhdr settings
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\FirstMark{2e-left}}  % first section
\fancyhead[R]{\FirstMark{2e-right-nonempty}}  % first subsection
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 
% End fancyhdr settings

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\thesection. #1}{}%
  }
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{%
    \markright{\thesubsection. #1}%
  }

% End header configuration

\begin{document}
\twocolumn

\section{First section}

\subsection{First subsection}

\lipsum[1-9]

\section{Second section}

Introduction

\subsection{Second subsection}

\lipsum[10]

\end{document}

I expect to get this header on page 2

Instead I get this


\FirstMark is supposed to return the first mark from that class in the current region. So isn't that what you'd expect?

hm, it feels a bit wrong, I too would have expected the page region to take both columns into account. I think you should report that in the github.

@cfr The region is the page, not the column. For the column as region you would have to use \FirstMark[column], but then you get the titles from the right column, which would be correct in the current example, but not if there is also a [sub]section in the left column.

On reflection, it does seem wrong it gives a different result.

@PietervanOostrum That seems unhelpful given that the documentation explicitly discusses use with fancyhdr? But it is specific to the fancy page style . fancyhdr's redefined headings works fine, for example.

You can partially reproduce without fancyhdr using the headings style followed by e.g. \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\leftmark\textbullet\rightmark\textbullet\FirstMark{2e-left}\textbullet\FirstMark{2e-right}\textbullet\FirstMark{2e-right-nonempty}}\hfil\thepage}% which shows that 2.1 isn't showing up as the first right mark on the page.

I've done some comment clean-up here that was about the bug system not the issue at hand
